# How should i join 4 tables using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate but had knowledge in some extent.

I have 4 tables `customer`, `Customer_header`, `Shop` and `Customer_template`. I would like to perform the following JOIN Query using Hibernate...

```
SELECT C.c_id, CH.c_des, S.s_num, CT.qty 
FROM CUSTOMER C, CUST_HEADER CH, SHOP S, CUST_TEMPLATE CT 
WHERE C.c_id = S.c_id AND C.c_id=CH.c_id AND CH.c_id=S.c_id AND CH.c_id=CT.c_id;
```

I have gone through some of the references. Some used `criteria` API and some used `HQL` Query. I didn't get how should I do that for 4 tables...

Please suggest me how can i do this ??

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Criteria is the primary way to work with hibernate. You have to watch the behaviour of your code: Prevent fetch loops for detail records, try to fetch as much of a joined record as possible at once. If criteria fails in that aspect, you can either look into HQL or create a database view and create a hibernate object for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you can use either `Criteria` or `HQL` to do this, here's the way to do it using HQL:

```
String queryString="C.c_id, CH.c_des, S.s_num, CT.qty FROM CUSTOMER C, CUST_HEADER CH, SHOP S, CUST_TEMPLATE CT WHERE C.c_id = S.c_id AND C.c_id=CH.c_id AND CH.c_id=S.c_id AND CH.c_id=CT.c_id";
Query query=session.createQuery(queryString);
List<Object[]> result=query.list();
```

You will get a list of `Object[]` arrays as a result where for each one, the first element of the array is `C.c_id`, the second is `CH.c_des`, third one is `S.s_num` and the last one is `CT.qty`.

Comment: is the elements returned are with same datatypes as they previously are like C.c_id(Number) ??

Comment: Yes these elements are of type `Object`, you just need to cast them to their initial typaes; e.g : `(int)obj`